# iOS devices cannot join AP created with hostapd if I enable EAP

Tags: hostapd

I am trying to create an 802.1x EAP access point using a Raspberry Pi 4 and hostapd.
It all seems to be working well on Windows as Windows devices can connect without issues, but when I try on iOS it gets to the point where the certificate of the RADIUS server comes up, I click Trust, and then it says Unable to join.
I can't figure out how to fix this as the rest of my setup seems to be working. iOS devices can join if it's an open or WPA2-PSK network, but as soon as I enable EAP they can no longer join.
I am using the following hostapd configuration:

```
interface=wlan0
driver=nl80211
ctrl_interface=/var/run/hostapd
ctrl_interface_group=0
channel=6
ieee80211n=1
ssid=Test-EAP-AP
wpa_pairwise=CCMP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
macaddr_acl=0 

#EAP Config 8021X
own_ip_addr=127.0.0.1
ieee8021x=1 


auth_algs=1
wpa=2
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-EAP

nas_identifier=other

#FreeRADIUS Server Config
auth_server_addr=127.0.0.1
auth_server_port=1812
auth_server_shared_secret=<my-secret>
```

I have the full hostapd logs for when an iOS device tries to join, but they are very very long so I will not post the full log here.